# How to prove that $a \in G \implies a^{k} \in H $ for some $k, 1 < k \le n$ if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was solving the following question with two parts.
We are given that $H < G$ with $[G : H ] = n < \infty$.

First of all, I don't understand what $[G : H ]$ means.

Then we are asked to show that:

$a \in G \implies a^{k} \in H$ for some $k, 1 \le k \le n$.

I am not sure really sure why this statement is true, and if this even is true for all cases. Can someone please help me write up a proof for this statement?

Comment: Hello $[G:H]$ is called the index. It is the number of cosets $gH$.

Comment: The supposed question for which this is tagged a duplicate is not a duplicate. I’m sure there is a past duplicate to this one somewhere, but that is not it. @dietrich.burde

Comment: This isn't the first time I see one user closing a question as duplicate when it is not. I'm not sure why such things are allowed here. By logic, there should be multiple votes in order to close a question.

Comment: I am sorry, I took the wrong duplicate. But it is, as Thomas said, a duplicate. The question is reopened.

Comment: @Mark: I think the relevant rule can be found here https://math.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions. A moderator can just close or reopen a question. I am inclined to agree with you that it should require multiple votes or a review by others if the reason for closing is a mathematical one (which is nearly always the case if the question is an alleged duplicate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[G:H]$ is the number of left cosets of $H$. I'll give a hint. Consider the following cosets:

$H, \  aH, \  a^2H,\  a^3H,..., a^nH$

Since $[G:H]=n$, two of these cosets have to be equal. Can you finish from here?

Comment: Hey, I am sorry, but I don't think I understand completely. 
1. I understand that 2 of these cosets must be equal, but which two or can that be arbitrary?
2. Even if two cosets were equal, why must it belong to H?

Comment: You don't know which two in general, you only know that two of them are the same. Try writing that down, and see whether you can do something with that equality to prove the claim.

Comment: @OnDragi Do I subtract the two values?

Comment: @Anonymous, formally the answer says: $\exists i,j, 0\le i<j\le n$ such that $a^iH=a^jH$, i.e. such that $a^{j-i}H=H$, i.e. ...(this is in multiplicative notation, so perhaps your "subtract" is the right idea).

Comment: @Anonymous Any two of them might be equal. Assume $a^iH=a^jH$ for some $0\leq i<j\leq n$. What does it imply?

Comment: @CAB But in this case, it cannot belong in H? So how do we go from there?

Comment: @Mark I m scared to apply in regular arithmetic operations to this since it is a group, but as someone mentioned this implies $a^{j-i}H = H$, but how this prove that it belongs to H? Just that it is equal to H?

Comment: @Anonymous If $e$ is the identity of $G$ then $e\in H$ (since $H$ is a subgroup) and so $a^{j-1}=a^{j-1}e\in a^{j-1}H$. Since $a^{j-i}H=H$ this implies $a^{j-i}\in H$.

Comment: @Anonymous I think you should learn a bit about cosets before you try to solve such exercises. In general, $g_1H=g_2H$ happens if and only if $g_1\in g_2H$, if and only if $g_2^{-1}g_1\in H$. In particular, $gH=H$ happens if and only if $g\in H$. All of these are basic facts about cosets. If you don't know all of these then of course you have difficulties with this exercise.